# How to fit a select tag in a table cell properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am desperately trying to make a select tag fit in a table cell like it belongs there, not like someone wedged it in with a crowbar.  Here is the code followed by the picture of how it appears:

```
<tr>
  <td class="lblCell_L" >ISIN Code </td>
  <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
   <select id='isinz' width="144" style="height:19px; width:140px; text-align:center;">
       <option id="ISIN1" onclick="JavaScript:quarterUpdate()" >A</option>
       <option id="ISIN2" onclick="JavaScript:quarterUpdate()" >B</option>
       <option id="ISIN3" onclick="JavaScript:quarterUpdate()" >C</option>
       <option id="ISIN4" onclick="JavaScript:quarterUpdate()" >E</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td class="lblCell_tx" id="isinOptions" style="color:#a56;">0</td>
</tr>
```

The way this comes out in FireFox:

[image: Select Tag has its own border inside the cell borders]

So, this is really ugly because the Select object has its own borders visible inside the cell, which has its own borders.  It is like stuffing a goose with pork... dismal looking!

Can the table cell borders be suppressed to allow the Select Tag borders to take their place?

You may notice, also, that the height of that cell is higher than the other "*text-only*" cell.

Comment: border-style:none; for td

Comment: select {border: none;}

Comment: wouldn't it be better to clear the select borders and add a height to the td?

Comment: The more the select element looks like it is part of the td, the less it looks like a form control, which is potentially confusing for the user.

Comment: Careful using `onclick` in `option` tags - it doesn't work in Safari/Chrome. I'm not sure about IE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Play with the border of the select (this may or may not work in Safari)

```
select {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is a JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EuNw4/

Also instead of a lot of `option onclick="JavaScript:quarterUpdate()"` use `select onchange"JavaScript:quarterUpdate()"`... **Inline Javascript like this shouldn't be used, you should do:**

```
// jQuery
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#isinz').on('change', quarterUpdate());
});
```

Comment: @Alex Excellent in simplicity and though obvious I was not even in the neighborhood!  You are a prince!

Comment: @Alex, quick question... onchange usually means typing something from my background (VFP).  How does that translate to clicking to trgger the event?

Comment: In `select` is fired when you select something. a click isn't always a  selection.

Answer (score 5):

From your question, I understand that this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/8vwV3/

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding:3px 10px;
}

td select {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide borders on the `select` element, for example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="lblCell_L">ISIN Code</td>
        <td id="ISINcb" class="lblCell_R" align="center">
            <select>
                <option id="ISIN1">A Abel</option>
                <option id="ISIN2">B Babel</option>
                <option id="ISIN3">C Cable</option>
                <option id="ISIN4">E Enable</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="lblCell_tx" id="isinOptions">0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS might be:

```
table {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
table td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
}
select { 
    width: 140px;
    border: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

You may not get much control over the down arrow in the select menu.

Make sure that you use `inherit` to keep the font-family and size consistent in the `select` menu.

The rest of my borders are eye-candy for the demo.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Em79R/

Comment: you can also set `outline: none;` for removing that blue (in Chrome) border which appears when it is focussed.