# Symfony 3, use enum type

Tags: symfony, orm, twig

With symfony I use enum type for the Etat attribute of my Status table. All goes well but what I want is that when I display the lists in my table view, Etat should be a select box with the values of my enum type, until it is the values selected from my database that appears.
I wonder how can I proceed so that in my table view, etat is a select box and his default value is the value already in the database.
here my code :

```
class Status{
    const ENVOYER = "Envoyé";
    const VALIDER = "Validé";
    const ANNULER = "Annulé";
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Etat", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $etat;
    /**
     * @param string $etat
     */
    public function setEtat($etat)
    {
        if (!in_array($etat, array(self::ENVOYER, self::VALIDER, self::ANNULER))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid status");
        }
        $this->etat = $etat;
    }
}
```

In my view

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for stat in status %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ stat.etat }}</td>
        </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Look at the choice type in documentation http://symfony.com/app.php/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: ok thanks, and so how I can set it in my table cell?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978632/how-to-fit-a-select-tag-in-a-table-cell-properly you have a exemple in a jsfiddle

Comment: ok, I ask you how can I set the choicetype in my table cell, so here this is an select options html.

Comment: Did you read the doc ? You have to use FormType with Symfony, and It will dispay a select in your view